# $ab \equiv 1 \ (n)$ implies $a$ and $b$ coprime with $n$? [Proof Verification]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

It's been a long time since I've touched anything related to elementary number theory, and I'm not convinced of my proof, which goes as follows:

Suppose that either $a$ or $b$ are not coprime with $n$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $b$ is not coprime with $n$. Now, this implies that there exists a prime $p$ that divides both $b$ and $n$. Since $ab \equiv 1 \ (n)$, there exists $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ab = dn + 1$, and therefore

$$
ab  \equiv dn + 1 \ (p)
$$

but since $p$ divides $b$ and $n$, we have

$$
0 \equiv 1 \ (p)
$$

which is absurd.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think this is fine. It's actually quite slick.

Comment: For the context of what I was doing, this seemed as too good to be true, but now having it written separately, I think I kinda see it. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Since this question is answered, you may write an answer below and accept it yourself, so you can close the question.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'm upvoting the question or the answer. :-)

Comment: Actually, $ab-dn=1$ implies that $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b,n)=1$.

Comment: I agree Arnaud.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг do you mean to copy the same argument that is embedded in the question as a separate answer?

Comment: @GuidoA.  Your answer is correct, therefore you should write your own answer by copying from above. It would be incorrect for anyone else to write an answer unless they are adding something more, which is unlikely, that's why I ask you to do it. Also +1 for the good question.

Comment: Okay, cool. Thanks, I'll do that then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since discussion in the comments indicates my original answer is correct, I'm copying it here to close the question.

*Proof.* Suppose that either $a$ or $b$ are not coprime with $n$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $b$ is not coprime with $n$. Now, this implies that there exists a prime $p$ that divides both $b$ and $n$. Since $ab \equiv 1 \ (n)$, there exists $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ab = dn + 1$, and therefore

$$
ab  \equiv dn + 1 \ (p)
$$

but since $p$ divides $b$ and $n$, we have

$$
0 \equiv 1 \ (p)
$$

which is absurd.